# Run Bluebird Promises Sequentially, without return values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

*This question has been asked in a variety of ways, but not quite as simply.*

How would this Promise.all be rewritten so that `promise1` runs completely before `promise2`?

```
var promise1 = function() { .. lots of promise stuff };
var promise2 = function() { .. lots more promise stuff };

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function() {
  log.info("ran promise1 & promise2");
});
```

*Promise.all runs promise1 & promise2 in parallel.*

Comment: Doesn't `each` run them serially? I don't recall.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, but .each produces: `Unhandled rejection TypeError: fn must be a function`

Comment: `Promise.all` does neither "run promises", nor call you functions. Your example doesn't even work.

Comment: Yes, this question has been asked many times. Why do you post another one that is "simpler"? Have you tried the solutions from the other answers? Please show us those attempts.

Comment: This question make little sense since you're telling people who provide answers that `promise1()` is undefined.  It should be very clear if you even care to look the doc for `Promise.all()` that it takes an array of promises so until your functions return promises and you call them and pass the return values to `Promise.all()`, this will never work.  A little study of the documentation and then implementing what it says the functions require would save you a lot of time.

Comment: @jfriend00 it takes array of anything, promises, thenables or immediate values or a mix of these types

Comment: @Esailija - the OP is passing an array of functions.  They likely intend to be passing an array of promises, but don't seem to understand that level of how this works which I'm encouraging them to read, understand and then implement.  BTW, what does `Promise.all()` do when you pass it an array of functions that are not promises or thenables?

Comment: @jfriend00 passing immediate values is same as passing promises resolved with those immediate values, it's just a convenience to avoid having to call `Promise.resolve(immediateValue)`

Answer (score 8):

You can use Promise.map with concurrency option set to 1.

```js
var promise1 = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("promise1 pending");
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("promise1 fulfilled");
            resolve();
        }, 1000)
    })
};

var promise2 = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("promise2 pending");
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("promise2 fulfilled");
            resolve()
        }, 50)
    })
};

Promise.map([promise1, promise2], function (promiseFn) {
    return promiseFn(); //make sure that here You return Promise
}, {concurrency: 1}); //it will run promises sequentially 

//It logs
//promise1 pending
//promise 1 fulfilled
//promise2 pending
//promise 2 fulfilled
```

Comment: This seems to work as you only have 2 Promise items in the array, if you add more, each with a setTimeout or some that resolve right away you will notice that the promises will resolve out of sync which makes the run non-sequential. This is due to how the js thread will work. For e.g. add promise3 with the same logic as promise2 and see the behaviour.

Comment: I've confirmed that this given solution wont work, sequential run is not guaranteed. This polyfill worked for me for a very complex sequential chain use case - https://bramanti.me/are-you-serial-promise-all/

Answer (score 2):

Use [then](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#thenfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise):

> Returns a new promise chained from this promise.

```
promise1().then(function() {
  return promise2();
}).then(function() {
  log.info("ran promise1 & promise2");
});
```

Comment: `promise1.then(function() { .. TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` .. is this because promise1 is not promisified?

Comment: are you sure `promise1` is a promise? if its a function that I assume returns a promise, as you have above then you'll need to call it first `promise1().then(..)`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: your answer makes sense, but for some reason promise1 and promise2 are undefined.. `TypeError: undefined is not a function` .. And curiously, logging promise1 and promise2 before performing Promise.all.. also logs `undefined` and `undefined`, but Promise.all runs perfectly (aside from running in parallel).. any suggestions?